# Perl regular expressions to parse SVG basic data types

Tags: regex, perl, svg

I am trying to collect all the perl regular expressions needed to validate SVG basic data types. So far I have:

```
my $w        = "\\s*";
my $hexdigit = "[0-9A-Fa-f]";
my $c        = "$w,$w";
my $i        = "[0-9]+";
my $integer  = "[+-]?$i";
my $p        = "${i}%";
my $number   = "(?:$integer|[+-]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+(?:[Ee]$integer)?)";
my $angle    = "(?:$number$w(?:deg|grad|rad)?)";
my $color    = "(?:#$hexdigit$hexdigit$hexdigit(?:$hexdigit$hexdigit$hexdigit)?|".
               "rgb\\($w$i$c$i$c$i$w\\)|".
               "rgb\\($w$p$c$p$c$p$w\\)|".
               '(?:'.join("|", sort keys %{svgColours()}). '))';
my $length     = "(?:$number(?:em|ex|px|in|cm|mm|pt|pc)?)";
my $coordinate = $length;
my $frequency  = "$number(?:Hz|kHz)";
my $FuncIRI    = "url\(.+\)";
my $numberOptionalNumber = "(?:$number|$number$c$number)"; 
my $paint      = "(?:fill|stroke)";
my $time       = "(?:$number(?:ms|s))";
```

Please let me know if you see opportunities for improvement.

Comment: As it doesn't seem that there is a specific problem you need to solve, you might want to ask this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were thinking the right thing (splitting the stuff into a composable grammar), but the way you did this has problems.

The most important problem is that many of your backslashes will be ignored. `"url\(.+\)" eq "url(.+)"`, `"... \. ..."` does not put a backslash before the period. To avoid the different parsing rules for strings and regexes, I urge you to use regex quotes: `qr//`. This has the side effect of compiling all these regexes (which you don't actually want), but at least you don't have to do double escaping:

```
my $w = qr/\s*/;
...
my $paint = qr/fill|stroke/; # enclosing group added automatically
```

However, each of these patterns must make sense as a regex on its own. Therefore, you need temporary variables for

```
my $color_names = join ...
my $color = qr/...|...|$color_names/;
```

When joining non-regex strings together, you should as a habit escape all metacharacters:

```
join '|', map quotemeta, keys %{ ... };
```

Instead of composing the regexes via variable interpolation, you can use `(?(DEFINE) ... )`:

```
qr/
  (?(DEFINE)
    (?<ws>      \s* )
    (?<comma>   \s*[,]\s* )
    (?<integer> [+-]?[0-9]+ )
    (?<percent> (?&integer)[%] )
    (?<number>  (?&integer)(?: [.][0-9]+ (?: [eE](?&integer) )? )? )
    ...
  )
/x
```

Inside a `DEFINE` environment, you can declare patterns as named captures (but they don't capture, and you can't capture inside such patterns). You can invoke such a pattern like `(?&pattern)`.

If you do not want to merely *match* the  data, but also to parse it, then regexes may not be suitable. I recommend the Marpa::R2 parser. This is a bit more low-level, and is less expressive, but has nice BNF syntax:

```
:start   ::= NumberList
:default ::= action => ::array bless => ::lhs
:discard ~ ws

NumberList ::= number+ separator => comma

ws      ~ [\s]+
comma   ~ ','
digits  ~ [0-9]+
sign    ~ [+-]
integer ~ sign digits | digits
number  ~ integer
        | integer '.' digits
        | integer '.' digits [eE] integer
...
```

Read the [Marpa documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/Marpa%3a%3aR2) to see if this libary could be useful. Otherwise, [Parse::RecDescent](https://metacpan.org/module/Parse%3a%3aRecDescent) and [Regexp::Grammars](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp%3a%3aGrammars) are good alternatives to plain regexes. If you choose a regex-based parser, you can reuse common patterns from [Regexp::Common](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp%3a%3aCommon).

Comment: (?(DEFINE): thanks for your extensive notes on this useful technique.